# ¿Cómo prevenir que se ejecute automáticamente este servicio? - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estoy haciendo un inicio de sesión en *AngularJS*, llamando un servicio que ejecuta llamadas `$http`:

```
userAccess.factory('accessFactory', function($http){
    var factory = {};

    factory.login = function(connectionInfo, execute){
        return $http.post('/login', connectionInfo);
    };

    factory.register = function(connectionInfo, execute){
        return $http.post('/register', connectionInfo); 
    };

    return factory;
})
```

En la directiva lo estoy llamando, de la siguiente manera:

```
userAccess.directive('loginModal', ['accessFactory', '$location', 
    function(accessFactory, $location){
        return{
            restrict: "C",
            scope: false, 
            link: function(scope, element, attr){ 

                scope.login = login();

                scope.register = register();

                function register(){
                    var data = {
                        'email' : scope.new_email,
                        'password' : scope.existing_password,
                    }

                    return access.register(data)
                        .then(registerSuccess, handleError);
                }

                function login(){
                    var data = { 
                        'email' : scope.existing_email,
                        'password' : scope.existing_password,
                    }

                    return access.login(data)
                        .then(loginSuccess, handleError);

                }
        ...
    }
}
```

... `success` y `error` son simples *"console.log"*, y todo funciona perfectamente.

El problema es que al cargar la página, esas dos llamadas se ejecutan automáticamente, haciendo el `request` al servidor, cosa que no debería pasar.

¿Cómo puedo inicializar el servicio sin que se ejecute automáticamente al requerirlo?

Answer (score 2):

Para cualquiera que le pueda servir, ya encontré el motivo, y es bien bobo:

Al realizar estas asiganciones:

```
scope.login = login();
scope.register = register();
```

Están siendo ejecutadas automáticamente, la forma correcta es no utilizar los paréntesis:

```
scope.login = login;
scope.register = register;
```

Saludos.